# Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found: Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, java-7

**When Launching the Android Studio getting this exception every time and project is not run.**

Error:Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found. Open Gradle Settings 
Platform SDK does not point to valid JDK (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home)

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit your project structure to point to a valid JDK location.

- From `File -> Project Structure`
- Set `SDK Location -> JDK location` to a Valid JDK Location like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75`

Answer (score 0):

I was having same kind of problem with my machine which has program files located on the network and `Java_Home` environment variable was pointing to the program files location which was on the network. I installed a local Java JDK and defined the JDK path in `Java_Home` environment variable. This worked for me.